# Difficulties in changing the background color of edit control

Tags: c++, winapi, editcontrol

I have edit control in a dialog box which input is checked for validity.

I should indicate validity by changing the background color of an edit control **if input is invalid**, otherwise **I should do nothing.**

I am checking the input in `EN_CHANGE` handler and if input is invalid I store the handle of the edit control in a vector. In the end I call `InvalidateRect( (HWND)lParam, NULL, TRUE );` so edit control can be repainted with proper color.

To repaint edit control I am handling `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` like this:

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
    {
        bool IsInvalid = false;  // does this edit control hold invalid text ?

        // vector InvalidInput contains handles of edit controls
        // with invalid input, so we check if our window is stored there
        for( vector<HWND>::size_type i = 0; 
            !IsInvalid && ( i < InvalidInput.size() ); i++ )
        {
            if( InvalidInput[i] == (HWND)lParam )
                IsInvalid = true;
        }

        // if input is invalid change background color to light gray
        if( IsInvalid )
        {
            // Needed SetBkMode for text background transparency 
            SetBkMode( (HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT ); 
            // return light gray brush 
            return (INT_PTR)( (HBRUSH)GetStockObject( LTGRAY_BRUSH ) );
        }
        else     
            return FALSE;   // say we didn't handle it 
                            // so dialog procedure can do that for us
    }
```

After I start the program edit control is painted properly.

After I type **valid entry** edit control is painted properly.

After I type invalid character **immediately after**, background is colored into light gray and everything seems to work fine.

If I delete the invalid character then the background **stays gray** instead of returning to default system color.

What am I doing wrong and how should I fix this ?

### EDIT:

If I put `InvalidateRect()` in my `WM_COMMAND` handler for `IDC_MYEDIT` then the problem seems to disappear:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch( LOWORD(wParam) )
        {
        case IDC_MYEDIT:
            {
                if( HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE )
                {
                    //do your validation stuff
                }
                InvalidateRect(...);
            }
            break;
        // the rest of the code...
```

Comment: n.m my earlier (deleted) comment. Can you try to move the `Invalid` test *out* of this redrawing function and check the one given in your input test? It might be a timing problem -- not all WM_xx messages appear in the queue in the order you expect them to.

Comment: I apologize, but I do not fully understand what you mean. Can you clarify a little? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: I thought you were testing *validity* but on second reading I see you are checking if the window was *tagged* as "invalid". Check if explicitly returning another brush on 'valid' works; that way you can see if the overall idea is sound.

Comment: @Jongware: The behavior is the same. However, if I remove `InvalidateRect` call from `EN_CHANGE` handler something happens that might be important: If I type `123` the color is OK. If I then paste letter ( edit control is numeric ) color does not change. After I delete that character **text background color** changes correctly but edits background color stays the same. Furthermore, if I change focus from edit control and then click again painting is done properly. Same is for minimize/maximize.

Comment: @Jongware: I have found "a solution" and documented it in edited part of my post. Can you take a look? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: I don't know why the message behaves differently depending on where you call `InValidateRect()`. I just want to comment that you can eliminate your `for` loop completely by using `std::find()` instead: `bool IsInvalid = (std::find(InvalidInput.begin(), InvalidInput.end(), (HWND)lParam) != InvalidInput.end());` in which case you can even geet rid of your `IsInvalid` variable as well and use `std::find()` in your `if( IsInvalid )` statement directly: `if( std::find(InvalidInput.begin(), InvalidInput.end(), (HWND)lParam) != InvalidInput.end() )`

Comment: When are you updating your "invalid" vector? If you're doing it on `EN_CHANGE` then the control has *already repainted itself*. Try doing it on `EN_UPDATE` instead.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes, I am doing it in `EN_CHANGE`. I do not know how to properly handle `EN_UPDATE` without entering endless recursion. This solution scares me even more since I have multiple edit controls. It seems that I will need a `bool` flag for every edit control in my `EN_UDATE` handler in order to avoid recursion. If you could provide code snippet or fairly detailed instructions on how to handle `EN_UPDATE`, and post them as a solution, I would accept your answer. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: `EN_UPDATE` is really handled exactly the same as `EN_CHANGE`, it just comes before the control has repainted rather than after.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes, but I need to watch out for recursion right? I know I am supposed to check a flag when handling `EN_UPDATE` but I do not know how to handle the case with multiple edit controls (do I need a flag for *every* edit control? ). Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: Please, "Thank you. Best regards." at the end of every question and comment is superfluous and noisy! Please desist. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: I'm not sure what recursion you're watching out for, that normally happens when you do something in response to a message that can trigger another message, so it depends on the code in question. There's nothing special about `EN_UPDATE` that makes it more likely to cause recursion than any other notification message.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I have edited my post with the peculiar effect I am facing. Can you please take a short look and try to help? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is here

```
    else     
        return FALSE;   // say we didn't handle it 
                        // so dialog procedure can do that for us
```

The `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` message is listed as [one of the special exceptions to the rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that returning `FALSE` means "not handled". It must be handled. If you don't want to handle it, you can pass the message to `DefWindowProc`.